# DataBase will not store in selected folder

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, datadirectory

I am trying to save my **database file** to a *specific folder*. I am using the following code to attempt this:

```
            dpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dpath);
            newConnectString = "Data Source=" + dpath + "\\" + filename;

            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[ConnectStringName].ConnectionString = newConnectString;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

When the program runs, the new file is never created in the destination folder. It is still storing it with the *executable*. Any insight as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only changes your configuration file, you will also need to File.Copy the database file to the required forlder, or use SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase with the new connection string.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I’m not sure it answers the question. I would like to File.Copy the database, but can’t get the correct path of |DataDirectory| to copy from. If I successfully changed the connection string in the configuration file, then the program should throw an error to tell me that the database doesn’t exist. Instead, it continues to access the database in the default |DataDirectory| folder which leads me to believe that although I’ve successfully changed the configuration file, I haven’t succeeded in connecting to it.